# Show/Hide Form Fields on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using JavaScript to show/hide additional fields in my form depending on whether the relevant checkbox is clicked. The fields are hidden and they do show when the checkbox is ticked, but **DO NOT** hide when it is un-ticked. However, the  fields do hide when I tick the checkbox again.

I have the checkbox with `id='cb_post'` and an `onclick` command to fetch `showDiv()` from my external javascript file.  I also have the hidden field with `id='hiddenDiv'`.

My javascript script is simple:

```
function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display == 'block') {
        (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'none');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block';

    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on how to hide the fields when the checkbox is unticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$("#hiddenDiv").hide();
$("#hiddenDiv").show();
```

and something nicer

```
$("#hiddenDiv").fadeOut();
$("#hiddenDiv").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using jQuery toggle would fit better for your problem:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_post">
<div id = "hiddenDiv">
<li>Toggle me</li>
</div>

$("#cb_post").on('click', function(){

    $("#hiddenDiv").toggle();

});
```

Maybe using the event `onchange` instead of `onclick` would be more elegant.

https://jsfiddle.net/qqL0sxxs/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code :**

```js
var chebx = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleField');

for (var i = 0; i < chebx.length; i++) {
  chebx[i].addEventListener('click', toggleField, false);
}

function toggleField() {
  var field = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target);

  if (field) {
    switch (this.checked) {
      case true:
        if (field.classList.contains('hide')) {
          field.classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
          field.classList.add('hide');
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<lable for='toggleField'>Toggle Field</lable>
<input type="checkbox" data-target='field1' class='toggleField'>

<input type='text' class='hide' id='field1' />
<hr>
<lable for='toggleField'>Toggle Field</lable>
<input type="checkbox" data-target='field2' class='toggleField'>

<input type='text' class='hide' id='field2' />
```